# Server: [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, html, web-services, server, tomcat8

My tomcat server always throws the following errors (Linux, Tomcat version is 8.5.4, using tail -f catalina.out):

The first error:

```
17-Jan-2017 10:39:24.982 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseCookies(Request.java:3047)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getServerCookies(Request.java:2098)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId(CoyoteAdapter.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17-Jan-2017 10:39:24.983 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest Error finishing response
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The second error:

```
17-Jan-2017 11:08:33.696 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest Error finishing response
 java.lang.NullPointerException

17-Jan-2017 11:08:33.743 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException

17-Jan-2017 11:08:33.743 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest Error finishing response
 java.lang.NullPointerException

17-Jan-2017 11:08:33.838 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException

17-Jan-2017 11:08:33.838 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest Error finishing response
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The third error:

```
17-Jan-2017 11:20:52.232 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.toChars(MessageBytes.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The front end html always print the errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

Backend server mainly use Spring, Jersey and the front end uses H5, AngularJS. Any idea, i will appreciate!

Comment: It can also happen, if you use `com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper` and its `getPreferredPrefix` returns an empty (or null) string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of tomcat that was introduced by the refactoring in 8.5.x onwards. You can search the tomcat bug list https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60918

You can solve the problem by upgrade the tomcat version, or modify the server.xml
set useSendfile="false"

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxHttpHeaderSize="16384" maxThreads="2000" connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true" redirectPort="8443" useSendfile="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this area but it seems like some sort of problem with request or cookies encoding. Might also be a tomcat bug.

For the first error can you try Rfc6265CookieProcessor.Please check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/cookie-processor.html) for details.

```
<Context>
....
    <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor" />
....
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occur when some problem with your tomcat version. Without a test case to reproduce the problem there is little the Tomcat developers can do. It looks like multiple threads are acting on the same socket at the same time. What I can't tell is if that is intentional, the result of a Tomcat bug or something the frameworks/app is doing.

I don't have much knowledge of this but i have fixed my issue [after ready this.](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53697)

> Other solution:-

This was also [asked before here](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/issues/301). It possible that which version of tomcat are you using?

For this exception

```
SEVERE: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

you need to [read this stack overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119143/org-apache-coyote-http11-http11protocolhttp11connectionhandler-process-severe)

The 502 Bad Gateway error is an HTTP status code that means that one server on the internet received an invalid response from another server.
For that you need to [read this tutorial.](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `http-nio-8080` with `http://localhost:8080` or `ip:8080`.